# Silverlight: How to draw images dynamically?

Tags: c#, image, silverlight-2.0

s.jpg added to solution with BuildAction==Resource.

**XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class=...>
    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot">            
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

**CS**

```
Image Model = new Image(); 
Model.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/s.jpg", UriKind.Relative)); 
LayoutRoot.SetLeft(Model, Coor.X); 
LayoutRoot.SetTop(Model, Coor.Y); 
Model.Width = 50; 
Model.Height = 30; 
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Model);
```

Here's my question: were is my image? It has't appeared on the screen, though if i change XAML to

```
<UserControl x:Class=...>
    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Image Source="s.jpg"></Image>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

you can see it, also if change CS to

```
Ellipse Model = new Ellipse(); 
Model.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
Model.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue); 
LayoutRoot.SetLeft(Model, Coor.X); 
LayoutRoot.SetTop(Model, Coor.Y); 
Model.Width = 50; 
Model.Height = 30; 
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Model);
```

i'll see that ellipse. so what the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

ImageSource imgSrc = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://server/path/s.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

LayoutRoot.Children.Add(imgSrc);
LayoutRoot.UpdateLayout();